# jquery dialog class selector each function

Tags: jquery, each, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to open jquery dialog on click of button. Problem is this with one button and one dialog it works well, but I have dynamically created pairs of dialogs and buttons. I am using jquery each function to initialize dialog, but it doesn't work.

My Php Code

```
echo '<div class="cp-button"> 
    <div class="popup" title="something"> $row[1] </div>
    <input type="button" value="Show Code" class="btnGetCode"/>';
 echo '</div>';
```

JQuery

```
$(".popup").each(function() {
    $(this).dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 880,
        height: 270,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 1000
        } 
    }); 
});

$(".btnGetCode" ).on( "click", function() {
    $(this).prev().dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
  $(".cp-button").on("click", ".btnGetCode", function(){
    //code
  });
});
```

EDIT: You need to have visible element when the page load
https://jsfiddle.net/orlandordzch/j7xfyL93/1/

Comment: try now with the example

Comment: can't implement the fiddle according to my scenarion, I am a beginner in jquery. Anyways thanks, got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out :)

HTML

```
echo '<div class="cp-button"> 
    <div class="popup" for="tag'.$i.'"> somehing </div>
    <input type="button" value="Show Code" class="btnGetCode" id="tag'.$i.'"/> </div>';
```

JQuery

```
var opt={    
           autoOpen: false,
           width: 880,
           height: 270,
           show: {
               effect: "blind",
               duration: 1000
           }     
        };

$(".popup").dialog(opt);
$(".btnGetCode").click(function()  {
     $(".popup[for='"+this.id+"']").dialog( "open" );
     return false;    
});
```